# Div clearfix remove white space

Tags: css, css-position, clearfix

My website has a header and a menubar.
I'd like to position them horizontally sticked to each other like this:

---

```
        HEADER
```

---

```
         MENU
```

---

But what happens is:

---

```
        HEADER
```

---

```
        WHITE SPACE
```

---

```
         MENU
```

---

The code for my header:

```
<div id="headersecure" class="clearfix">
   <div class="headeritem"><a href="#">Uitloggen</a></div>
   <div class="headeritem"><a href="#" onclick="loadX()">X</a></div>
   <div class="headeritem headerfoto"><a href="#" onclick="loadX(()">Test</a></div>
   <div class="headeritem"><a href="#" onclick="loadQ()">W</a></div>
   <div class="headeritem"><a href="#" onclick="loadQC()">Contact</a></div>
</div>
```

The header css code:

```
#headersecure {
    padding-left: 10%;
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: LANENAR;
}

.headeritem {
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 30px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

The code for my menubar:

```
<div id="headermenu" class="clearfix">
   <div class="menuitem"><a href="#" onmouseover="" onclick="loadA()"><img src="images/a.png">A</a></div>
   <div class="menuitem"><a href="#" onmouseover="" onclick="loadB()"><img src="images/b.png">B</a></div>
   <div class="menuitem"><a href="#" onmouseover="" onclick="loadC()"><img src="images/c.png">C</a></div>
   <div class="menuitem"><a href="#" onmouseover="" onclick="loadD()"><img src="images/d.png">D</a></div>
   <div class="menuitem"><a href="#" onmouseover="" onclick="loadE()"><img src="images/e.png">E</a></div>
   <div class="menuitem"><a href="#" onmouseover="" onclick="loadF()"><img src="images/f.png">F</a></div>
   <div class="menuitem"><a href="#" onmouseover="" onclick="loadG()"><img src="images/g.png">Test12313131311</a></div>
 </div>
```

The css code for the menu:

```
#headermenu {
    padding-left: 10%;
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    top: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    font-family: LANENAR;
}

.menuitem {
    height: 25px;
    width: 8%;
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

The clearfix css code:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

Because both of them use float, whenever the menubaritems are on the same horizontal level as the headeritems, they start to position the wrong way.

Instead of using class: clearfix, I also tried putting a div between them, like this:

```
<div style="clear:both;"> </div>
```

My problem is, that both solutions create an empty space between the menu and the header.
I also tried setting all margins, padding etc to 0, but that doesn't help.

// edit: fiddle with div style clear both: http://jsfiddle.net/XJ3QE/3/
screenshot:[image]

// edit: screenshot in Chrome 28
[image: http://s11.postimg.org/pyk7jajgz/image.png]

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/XJ3QE/ No whitespace there. Perhaps something else is interfering with your CSS?

Comment: That was because the menuitems didn't have the same horizontal position as the headeritems.

I edited the above code, instead of using menuitem G, I made it Test12313131311, just as an example. Now you see what goes wrong.

Comment: Still no white space. How about you supply a jsFiddle that shows the problem rather than me trying to reproduce your error?

Comment: Sorry...here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/XJ3QE/2/

It goes well in Firefox 11, but the problem occurs in Chrome

Comment: No white space in Chrome 28, Firefox 22 or IE 10. By the way, your `img` tags are not closed. Can you post a screenshot maybe?

Comment: Not seeing any white space here either.

Comment: FireFox 11? Which version of chrome are you using then?

Comment: Screenshots added. Ps, thanks for the img closing tip. Will do that when I get the chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is just the free space between header and menu, it is because of `height of h.headeritem`. it removed like [This Link](http://jsfiddle.net/XJ3QE/5/).

By deleting `height: 100%;` , the `.headeritem` is like this :

```
.headeritem {
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 30px;
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Edit Part :
As is clear from the screenshot, `Test12313131311` is below of `headermenu`, it's because of `width` of `menuitem`.
You can change it to 13% or a pixel size :

```
.menuitem {
    height: 25px;
    width: 13%; /* or width: 140px */
    float: left;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: Well, there are 2 problems.
1) The white space if I use div style: clear.
2) The fact that the menuitem with the same horizontal position as the headeritem is positioned below the menubar.

Problem 1 is solved with the height solution, problem 2 isn't...

Comment: you mean `Test12313131311` that is below other items in `headermenu` ?!

Comment: Yes. Like in the screenshot, you see c, d, e, f etc in the menubar all at the same height.
Except for Test12313131311, that is not in the menubar, because of the headeritems above it. Hope that's fixable.

Comment: Indeed, the 1 image in the headermenu caused the white space between them. Thanks!